# Object of the class Row with different length

Tags: apache-spark, row

I can create an object of the class Row as:

```
Row row = RowFactory.create(1,2,3);
```

This Row object has a length 3. 
How is it possible to create the row Object for example of the length 10000 without to type every value manual (for example filling with the random numbers)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like

```
Row row = RowFactory.create((1 to 10000).toList);
```

With random values:

```
Row row = RowFactory.create((1 to 10000).map ( Random.nextInt).toList);
```

Comment: ok, I'm going to accept this. It was my mistake, have already done this method, but have got en error message early...